# Draw Circle out of squares- GD Library in C

Tags: c, computer-science

I am having some trouble with this project, I am supposed to use the GD.h library to construct an image with a black background and draw a circle out of squares.
I have to use this library to construct the image and I am not allowed to use any other function other than "gdImageRectangle" to make the circle out of squares. 
I have my code all made up to make and export the image but after my color array I cannot figure out how to make the circle..also any tips/tutorials on gd.h would be appreciated. I read the manual but still can't fully understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gd.h>

#define BLACK           0
#define BLUE            1
#define GREEN           2
#define RED             3
#define WHITE           4

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char                    *outfile;                                                                                               //name out of the output file
    FILE                    *out;                                                                                           //output file pointer
    gdImagePtr               img;                                                                                           //GD Image Contruct
    unsigned int             color[5];                                                                                      //color array
    unsigned short int       wide, high;                                                                                    //image attributes

    if (argc == 2)
    {
            outfile = *(argv+6);
            fprintf(stdout, "Using '%s' as output filename\n", outfile);
    }
    else
    {
            outfile = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * 64);
            strcpy(outfile, "/home/snicho15/public_html/cos0.png");
    }

    //setting up image width and height for COS0
    wide = 800;
    high = 600;

    //create new image with specified height and width
    img = gdImageCreate(wide, high);

    //GD COLOR
    color[BLACK]             = gdImageColorAllocate(img, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    color[BLUE]              = gdImageColorAllocate(img, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
    color[GREEN]             = gdImageColorAllocate(img, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00);
    color[RED]               = gdImageColorAllocate(img, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    color[WHITE]             = gdImageColorAllocate(img, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    //code goes down here

   **where the circle out of squares code goes**

    //open file
    if((out = fopen(outfile, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
             fprintf(stderr, "Error opening '%s'\n", outfile);
             exit(1);
    }

    //send image to file
    gdImagePngEx(img, out, -1);

    //close things up
    fclose(out);
    gdImageDestroy(img);

    return (0);
    }
```

Mainly the only thing I need help with is how to draw the circle out of squares. the center x of the circle is supposed to be 0 and along with center y (should be 0). I am satisfied with everything to that point. I can get it compile plus create images just stuck on the circle.

Comment: Have you managed to draw *one* square at the centre of the circle, as a test? If so, draw a square at each of the four orthogonal points, on the X and Y axes, at the radius. Then, find a way to fill those in-between radial points, either by using an angle, or a Bresenham circle algorithm.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have not. I was still kind of confused as to how I would draw a circle with just using the gdImageRectangle function...

Comment: Consider that very small rectangles are pixels. Draw each rectangle at the point you want a pixel to be.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are supposed to construct a *filled* circle, draw filled rectangles at the centre, starting with a tall thin one, thru a square, to a flat long one, computing the required size of each rectangle ;-)